# Was Mîm trying to perform some kind of magic?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, children-of-hurin

In *The Children of Húrin*, there is the following interesting passage:

> They led the old Dwarf away to their dismal camp, and as he went he
> muttered in a  strange tongue that seemed harsh with ancient hatred;
> but when they put bonds on his  legs he went suddenly quiet. And those
> who were on the watch saw him sitting on  through the night silent and
> still as a stone, save for his sleepless eyes that glinted as they
> roved in the dark.
>
> [...]
>
> Mim opened his eyes and pointed to his bonds; and when he was
> released he spoke  fiercely. 'Learn this, fools!' he said. 'Do not put
> bonds on a Dwarf! He will not forgive it.  I do not wish to die, but
> for what you have done my heart is hot. I repent my promise.'

Later, Mîm says the following:

> 'This is my son. An arrow was in his breast. Now he is beyond speech. He died at sunset.
> Your bonds held me from healing him.'

As well as:

> '[...]Do I not remember that your hands were among those that put
> bonds upon me, and so held me that I did not speak again with my son? [...]'

It is possible that Mîm simply means that, because of his bonds, he couldn't have escaped and gone home to heal his son. However, to me, it seems like it is suggested that Mîm was trying to perform some sort of magic, in order to communicate with his son or heal him (or both), which his bonds prevented him from empolying (since it required the use of his hands).

So, which is it? Is there any more evidence on this anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No pretty sure it means he couldn't leave and go help his son.

For starters, the bonds were on his legs, not his hands. It even says he has free use of his hands, as he's able to point to the bonds before they are removed.

I'm not aware of any instances of Dwarves (or anyone) performing healing at a distance, through waving their hands or otherwise.